# c# datagridview: How to replace specific value after matching another value into the same row?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a dataGridView which contains

```
FabricName---QuantityInShop---QuantityInWarehouse
```

I have textFields for

```
FabricName, RemainingQuantityInShop, QuantityInShop
```

Now, how can I replace QuantityInShop with RemainingQuantityInShop value for matched FabricName in DatagridView?

Comment: I will take input from textboxes, then will compare value with datagridview, if any match found, I want to replace value of another cell of the same row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the simple Form that you want:

[image]

and here is your `button_click` event

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        if (dataGridView1[0, i].Value != null)
            if (dataGridView1[0, i].Value.ToString() == txtKey.Text)
                dataGridView1[1, i].Value = txtValue.Text;
    }
}
```

then the *Row 0 and 2* is replaced to "User"